# plot qualitative data on matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have three 1D arrays of same length. These are:

1. Temperature (F)
2. wind speed
3. wind direction

temperature and wind speed have all float values while wind direction has string values like 'south', 'north', 'northeast', 'west', etc. Now, I want to create a 3D scatterplot with these arrays..what is the possible way (since the wind direction array has string values)? Can some logic be applied to this scenario?

Comment: Did you try creating a dictionary with the directions as keys, and the contents being unit vectors in the appropriate direction? You could then loop through your string array and create a corresponding numerical array.

Comment: Are you saying that I can replace my array of wind direction with appropriate numerical values..like 1 = south, 2 = north, 3 = northwest, etc. etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @pwagner, I would go for a polar plot, but for 3D one. Basically what you can do is re-map your winds to polar degrees, as in example below:

```
angles = {'east':0, 'northeast':np.pi/4, 'north':np.pi/2, 'northwest':3*np.pi/4,
          'west':np.pi, 'southwest':5*np.pi/4, 'south':3*np.pi/2, 'southeast':7*np.pi/4}
wind_angle = np.array([angles[i] for i in wind])
```

This will give you wind directions; then you can transform your (wind, speed) coordinates to cartesian and plot it by 3D scatter. You even can code your temperature in colormap, with full example shown below:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

wind_dirs = ['east', 'northeast', 'north', 'northwest',
             'west', 'southwest', 'south', 'southeast']
# data
speed = np.random.uniform(0,1.25,100)
temp = np.random.uniform(-10,20,100)
wind = [wind_dirs[i] for i in np.random.randint(8, size=100)]

#transform data to cartesian
angles = {'east':0, 'northeast':np.pi/4, 'north':np.pi/2, 'northwest':3*np.pi/4,
          'west':np.pi, 'southwest':5*np.pi/4, 'south':3*np.pi/2, 'southeast':7*np.pi/4}
wind_angle = np.array([angles[i] for i in wind])
X,Y = speed*np.cos(wind_angle),speed*np.sin(wind_angle)

ax.scatter3D(X, Y, temp, c = temp, cmap=cm.bwr)
ax.set_zlabel('Temp')
plt.show()
```

which results in a nice graph which can be rotated and zoomed at:

[image]

Comment: I have the array of corresponding wind directions. Can i replace it at wind = [wind_dirs[i] for i original_wind_direction_array]? I think that'll work..right?

Comment: Yes, it should. My initial `wind` array is also a list of wind directions, although random ones. You can check it by inserting `print wind` in the code.

Comment: one last question Andrey..A part from south, north and other realistic directions, I have one reading in the wind direction array which says 'Variable'...:-). I am thinking to assign it '0' degrees..what do you think? Any better suggestion?

Comment: That's a good question... 0 degrees is east direction, so if you assign it to 0, you'll not be distinguishing variable and east winds. So here I see 3 approaches: 1. assign variable wind speed so some angle like `3*np.pi/8`, which is not in the list of 'physical' directions; 2. assume that variable wind speed on average equals 0, and plot all the variable points in the center (but you lose info on wind speed); 3. plot variable points as circles with radius equal to wind speed and height equal to temperature (if you have many such points the graph will be overloaded).

Comment: I think I will go with the 3*np.pi/8 thing because this is what I had in my mind. I will create an exception on that because the 'Variable' entries aren't many. Thanks Andrey. :-)

Comment: It is giving this error while i am declaring wind = [wind_dirs[i] for i in original_wind_dir].

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#61>", line 1, in <module>
    wind = [wind_dirs[i] for i in newyork_wind_dir]
ValueError: field named South not found.

Comment: You do not need the whole chunk of code under `data` comment. It's simply the initialization of random test data. You can delete it and change `wind_angle` line to `wind_angle = np.array([angles[i] for i in newyork_wind_dir])` (don't forget to uppercase the first letters in `angles` dictionary as obviously you have your wind direction starting from the capital letter).

Comment: Andrey, your responses were very helpful. Thanks. I have one last query remaining about the issue of putting values in x, y and z axes. In your code, you put X,Y = speed*np.cos(wind_angle),speed*np.sin(wind_angle) while I want  to simply put X,Y = temp, relative_humidity as X and Y and put wind_angles as Z. What is the point of sin() and cosine() and multiplying with wind_angle? Can't I simply put X, Y, Z as temp, relative_humidity, wind_angles respectively?

Comment: also, what is the point of setting c = temp? what is the significance of setting temperature and any other variable as color?

Comment: Everything is done for better visualization of data. I take `speed` as polar radius and `angle` as polar angle; `r*cos(phi)` is just the transformation of polar coordinates to cartesian, and the color of point is just another coordinate. I think that this representation makes it easy to see correlations in data - whether stronger winds blow in the eastern direction and bring warm air or not. You are free to do with your data whatever you like, for sure, but in my work I visualize large arrays in the way I described.

Answer (score 4):

You could define a dictionary angles that defines the angle between the x-axis (east direction) and the wind direction like:

```
angles = {'East': 0., 'North': math.pi/2., 'West': math.pi, 'South': 3.*math.pi/2.}
```

Then you can calculate the velocity in x (east) and y (north)  direction as in following example:

```
import math

angles = {'East': 0., 'North': math.pi/2., 'West': math.pi, 'South': 3.*math.pi/2.}

directions = ['East', 'North', 'West', 'South']
vtot = [1.5, 2., 0.5, 3.]
Temperature = [230., 250. , 200., 198.] # K

vx = [vtot[i]*math.cos(angles[directions[i]]) for i in range(len(directions))] # velocity in x-direction (East)
vy = [vtot[i]*math.sin(angles[directions[i]]) for i in range(len(directions))] # velocity in y-direction (North)

print (vx)
print (vy)
```

Then you can plot `vx`, `vy`, and `Temperature` in any 3D plot of matplotlib.

Comment: yeah..I am going through a very same logic...but in a bit different way.

Answer (score 0):

As I'm reading this question I must think of a polar plot (naturally for wind directions) and the temperature encoded as color. A quick search brought up an existing [matplotlib example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/polar_scatter.html).
Rewriting the example it could look like the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

N = 150
r = 2.0 * np.random.randn(N)
theta = 2.0 * np.pi * np.random.randn(N)
area = 10.0 * r**2.0 * np.random.randn(N)
colors = theta
ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)
c = plt.scatter(theta, r, c=colors, cmap=cm.hsv)
c.set_alpha(0.75)

ticklocs = ax.xaxis.get_ticklocs()
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels([chr(number + 65) for number in range(len(ticklocs))])

plt.show()
```

I hope you can adopt the example even further to your needs.

Comment: This is interesting but what I am willing to have is a 3D scatterplot with its z axis as wind direction, x as temperature and y as wind speed.